# I'm using click event to trigger CSS animation, why wouldn't the animation run again when clicked again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom

I'm new to web dev, I'm trying to get a better understanding on DOM.

The purpose of my code is to give an element some animation when a click event is triggered. Here's what I tried:

Code:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  svg.style.animation = 'svg-color 5s linear 1 1s';
}
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

@keyframes svg-color {
  0% {
    background-color: lightcyan;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: steelblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="300" height="300"></svg>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

It works on the first click event. But when I click the button again, the animation won't run again.

Is this issue due to DOM or the fact that I have set animation-iteration-count as 1 on CSS?

And if I set animation-iteration-count as infinite, is there a way to make the animation goes back to its start state and replay again on click event?

Comment: Because you're assigning the same style that's already set on the element. You should remove the style when the animation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens if you assign a style that's already set on the element.

You need to remove the style when the animation ends. That way, the style will be new the next time you click.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  svg.style.animation = 'svg-color 5s linear 1 1s';
}
svg.addEventListener("animationend", (e) => e.target.style.animation = '');
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

@keyframes svg-color {
  0% {
    background-color: lightcyan;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: steelblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="300" height="300"></svg>
<button id="button">button</button>
```